# How to create rule for .o files from 2 different folders with .c files using makefile

Tags: makefile

I want to have the possibility to build output files from different folders depending on the command.

./source_files/ - folder with *.c files for `make build2` and `make unit_test` commands.

./source_files/unit_test/ - folder with *.c files for `make unit_test`commands

I have 2 commands:

1. this works - command `make build2` should take files `./source_files/*.c`, make `./build/*.o` from them and create <name.a> library;
2. this doesn't work - command `make unit_test` should take files `./source_files/*.c` and also `./source_files/unit_tests/*.c` make `./build/*.o` from them and create test.out file.

`make unit_test` generates the output:
`make: *** No rule to make target 'build/test_main.o', needed by 'unit_test'.  Stop.`

I have 2 rules for *.o files. I guess I have to combine them into one, but I have no idea how to do that. Can you help me with it, please?

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(UNITSRCS)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@
```

makefile:

```
#Compiler flags
CC := gcc
INCLDIR := -I./includes
LIBS := -lcunit

#Directories and files
BUILDDIR := build

SRCDIR := source_files
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

UNITDIR := $(SRCDIR)/unit_tests
UNITSRCS := $(wildcard $(UNITDIR)/*.c)
UNITOBJS := $(UNITSRCS:$(UNITDIR)/%.c=$(BUILDDIR)/%.o)

STLIB := $(BUILDDIR)/libbinary_tree.a

$(BUILDDIR):
    mkdir $(BUILDDIR)

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@

$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(UNITSRCS)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
    $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@

.PHONY: unit_test
unit_test: $(OBJS) $(UNITOBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(UNITOBJS) $(INCLDIR) $(LIBS) -o $(BUILDDIR)/test_main.out

.PHONY: build2
build2: $(OBJS)
    ar -rcs $(STLIB) $(OBJS)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -r $(BUILDDIR)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule is OK:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
        $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@
```

But this rule is wrong:

```
$(BUILDDIR)/%.o: $(UNITSRCS)/%.c | $(BUILDDIR)
        $(CC) -c $< $(INCLDIR) -o $@
```

Just as in the first rule, you want to have `$(UNITDIR)/%.c` not `$(UNITSRCS)/%.c`.  After make expands the variable the latter will clearly be wrong.

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry for my inattention